# Improving ERC20 transfer

Tags: solidity, erc-20, wallet-transfer

I'm wanting to accept stablecoin transfers and currently have independent operations to handle the payments yet concerned this will lead to faulty interactions, lost funds, and incorrect execution:

```js
    function depositDAI() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= amount, "Insufficient funds");
        transferFunds(DAI, 10**18);
    }

    function depositUSDC() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= amount, "Insufficient funds");
        transferFunds(USDC, 10**6);
    }
    
    function depositUSDT() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= amount, "Insufficient funds");
        transferFunds(USDT, 10**6);
    }
```

Would it be possible to handle these operations in a single function? I would like to  check:

1. the ERC20 is supported
2. `amount` of ERC20 is sufficient
3. available for direct interaction with wallet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets begin from there that if you don't want to receive ETH your functions doesn't have to be `payable`.

For points 1) and 2) this code will help:

```
interface ERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool);
}

contract Name {
    mapping(address -> bool) supportedStableCoins;
    mapping(address -> uint) minAmauntForSuportedStableCoin;

    function addCoin(address _coinAddress, uint _minAmount) external {
        require(supportedStableCoins[_coinAddress] == true, "Already added");
        supportedStableCoins[_coinAddress] = true;
        minAmauntForSuportedStableCoin[_coinAddress] = _minAmount;
    }

    function deposit(address _coinAddress, uint _amount) external {
       require(supportedStableCoins[_coinAddress] == true)
       require(minAmauntForSuportedStableCoin[_coinAddress] <= _amount);
       require(ERC20(_coinAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount));
}
```

Note 1: In order to execute `transferFrom` the message sender first must have `approved` the `_amount` to the contract.

Note 2: You must have `constructor` and some modifiers to the `addCoin` function. You don't want every one to add coins to your contract.

Regarding point 3) if you provide front end functionality to make transaction everything would be out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the great writeup! I'm still having difficulty understanding how this works: is `_coinAddress` under the `deposit` function the address of the sender's wallet or would the sender be enforced to send the token address? If the latter, would there be a way to infer the address to avoid having them specify the address of the token? Also, in regards to `approve` would that be a separate call or could it be added above `transferFrom`?

Comment: No, every stable coin DAI/USDC/USDT is also a contract, this contract have specific functions which are well known under the name of ERC20 interface also their contracts have address. `_coinAddress` is their contract's address

Comment: For eg here is the USDC contract - https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for someone transferring USDC to the contract and the contract identifying it is USDC-- here the user needs to tell the contract the address of the token, which may be spoofed. I don't think this is the solution I am looking for :(

Comment: Here you can get a better idea for ERC20 tokens - https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/understanding-erc-20-token-contracts-a809a7310aa5

Comment: But you have registered the valid token address with the`addCoin` and if the user send unregistered the function will revert

Comment: Yes, but the user must send the contract address with the request and `ERC20()` would succeed with any ERC20 even if not matches. I previously tried `balanceOf`, I will experiment. Your feedback is helpful, thank you

Comment: This turned out to be exactly what I needed, thanks!